# How to use miniz to create a compressed file that can be decompressd by gzip?

Tags: c++, gzip, miniz

I'm writing a program in C++, on windows platform. I would like to compress some data storing in a `char[]` array, and output it to a file, and later I will upload the file to a unix server and I want it can be decompressed by `gzip -d`.

After a lot of research, I choose [miniz](http://code.google.com/p/miniz/). Also, I found the gzip file format [here](http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/formats/gzip.html).

Here is the code snippet of creating gzip file: (sorry I didn't put the definition of some variables; they're defined somewhere else)

```
unsigned long zsize;
zpkg[0] = 0x1F;
zpkg[1] = 0x8B;
zpkg[2] = 8;
zpkg[3] = 0;
zpkg[4] = 0;
zpkg[5] = 0;
zpkg[6] = 0;
zpkg[7] = 0;
zpkg[8] = 0;
zpkg[9] = 0xFF;
compress2(zpkg + 10, &zsize, pkg, pkgSize, MZ_DEFAULT_LEVEL);
int footerStart = (int)zsize + 10;
mz_ulong crc = mz_crc32(MZ_CRC32_INIT, zpkg + 10, zsize);
zpkg[footerStart] = crc & 0xFF;
zpkg[footerStart + 1] = (crc >> 8) & 0xFF;
zpkg[footerStart + 2] = (crc >> 16) & 0xFF;
zpkg[footerStart + 3] = (crc >> 24) & 0xFF;
zpkg[footerStart + 4] = pkgSize & 0xFF;
zpkg[footerStart + 5] = (pkgSize >> 8) & 0xFF;
zpkg[footerStart + 6] = (pkgSize >> 16) & 0xFF;
zpkg[footerStart + 7] = (pkgSize >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

And later just output the `zpkg` array to a file. However this doesn't work; when I decompress it with gzip, the error messsage is:

```
gzip: data stream error
gzip: test.gz: uncompress failed
```

Can anybody please point me out what I'm doing wrong?

---

---

Thanks for Mark Adler and Michael, I figure out a working solution.

First, as Mark pointed out, I should make miniz return a raw deflate data stream. This can be done by passing `-MZ_DEFAULT_WINDOW_BITS` (notice the minus sign) to `mz_deflateInit2()` as the fourth parameter. Looking into the miniz source code, the `compress2()` function eventually calls the `mz_deflateInit2()` with `MZ_DEFAULT_WINDOW_BITS`, which means adding zlib header and footer. So the easiest fix is adding a minus sign there, so that I can still use the `compress2()` function. (this works for me because I only call this function at one place)

Second, as Michael pointed out, the CRC code should be calculated on uncompressed data. So I fix it like this:

```
mz_ulong crc = mz_crc32(MZ_CRC32_INIT, pkg, pkgSize);
```

After making the two changes above, `gzip -d` doesn't complain anymore.

Comment: _"CRC32 (CRC-32) This contains a Cyclic Redundancy Check value of the **uncompressed** data"_ ([source](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1952)). It looks to me like you're CRC'ing the **compressed** data.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that is another thing that I'm not sure, but I did try to break the CRC code of a valid gzip file and see what's the error message, and it is "gzip: invalid compressed data--crc error". So I believe this is not the root cause of my issue.

Comment: Well, it's one thing that probably needs to be fixed anyway. How are you writing the data to file exactly? Have you opened the resulting file in a hex editor and made sure that it looks like you expect it to? Have you compared it to a file compressed with some other utility?

Comment: I use ofstream to output it to a file. Actually this is just for testing, the real scenario will be upload it to server through WinHTTP, but that is not related to my question so I didn't mention it. I did try to compress the same data with gzip, and the content is totally different. Since the document of miniz said that it is compatible with zlib, so I just assume that the compress2() function can give me the gzip body, but looks like it does not. So I'm wondering if I use the miniz library correctly? Or I'm wrong, there is a right answer? Or I can't use miniz this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compress2()` produces a zlib stream, which is deflate compressed data with a zlib header and trailer.  For what you are doing, you want just the raw deflate compressed stream to stick in your manually generated gzip header and trailer.

You could either: a) discard the first two and last four bytes of the output of `compress2()` to strip the zlib header and trailer, b) use `deflateInit2()`, `deflate()`, and `deflateEnd()` instead of `compress2()` and select the raw deflate format, or c) use those same functions and instead select the gzip format, and get rid of your manually constructed gzip header and trailer since `deflate()` will do that for you.

I recommend c).

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I can't figure our how to tell miniz to use gzip format, and actually in the miniz source code, there's a comment saying that it doesn't support gzip header. Your suggstion b) works best for me, I have updated the solution above and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the question and answers above, I was able to write the working code.

```
#include "miniz_cpp.hpp" //https://github.com/nyq/miniz-cpp/tree/master
                         //based on miniz 3.0.2
using namespace miniz_cpp;
void Save_gz_file(std::string sFileName, std::string &data)
{
    std::string sDeflated = "";
    unsigned long iDeflated = data.length()*2+18;
    sDeflated.reserve(iDeflated);
    sDeflated.append("\x1f\x8b\x08\0\0\0\0\0\0\xff", 10);

    mz_stream stream;
    memset(&stream, 0, sizeof(stream));

    stream.next_in = (unsigned char *) data.data();
    stream.avail_in = (mz_uint32) data.length();
    stream.next_out = (unsigned char *) (sDeflated.data() + 10);
    stream.avail_out = (mz_uint32) iDeflated;

    int result = mz_deflateInit2(&stream, MZ_BEST_COMPRESSION,
                 MZ_DEFLATED, -MZ_DEFAULT_WINDOW_BITS, 9,
                 MZ_DEFAULT_STRATEGY);

    if(result == MZ_OK)
    {
        result = mz_deflate(&stream, MZ_FINISH);
        if(result == MZ_STREAM_END) 
        {
            std::ofstream some_file(sFileName);
            some_file.write(sDeflated.data(), stream.total_out + 10); 
            uLong crc = mz_crc32(MZ_CRC32_INIT, (mz_uint8*) (data.data()),
                                 data.length());
            some_file.write((const char*) &crc, 4);
            uLong len = data.length();
            some_file.write((const char*) &len, 4);                            
        }
        mz_deflateEnd(&stream);   
    }
}
```